# deserialize XmlObjectSerializer document

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have no idea about how deserialize an XML Document that arrive in a WCF service.

```
Example of XML
<PERSON>
  <NAME>MyName</NAME>
  <SURNAME>MyName</SURNAME>
</PERSON>
```

I wrote a class Person:

```
[XmlRoot("PERSON")]
public class PERSON
{
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Surname")]
    public DateTime Surname { get; set; }
}
```

Below I should implement the method:

```
public bool OperationWardrobes(XmlObjectSerializer document)
{
    if (document == null)
        return false;
    else{
        //Deserialize a document and get information in variables
        }
}
```

Anyone can help me please?
Thanks in advance.
Wiper

Comment: The idea is that you should have a link to the `wsdl`. It will generate client classes and use. Don't need a manual parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've never come across that XmlObjectSerializer you're using, but you can certainly do it by loading it into an XDocument.

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

    public bool OperationWardrobes(XDocument document)
    {
        if (document == null)
            return false;

        try
        {
            // no need for else here
            Person person = null;
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
            using (var reader = document.CreateReader())
            {
                person = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                // do stuff
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // log ex
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Great, thank's for your answer. 
Instead, regarding " // no need for else here " you are definitely right, it was an oversight.